# Why can I see the variable in the URL but the variable contains NULL when using GET

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a WordPress child theme and a custom page template. A separate folder in the child theme directory connects to an external database outside of this WordPress install. All database connections are good!

I am having a problem reading a 'test' variable passed from a link to another PHP page. Both pages exist in WordPress but each page are using a different page template - passing a variable between page templates!!

The HTML and PHP code from the first template (Wordpress Page) sends on link click to the other

```
<a href="http://websiteurl.co.uk/?page_id=93?test=<?php echo $test->id; ?>" title="View the test photos">View Photos</a>
```

The destination URL reads: websiteurl.co.uk/?page_id=93?test=162

To see if the variable is being passed correctly before continuing I dumped the variable, however the variable contents displayed NULL

```
<?php var_dump(count($_GET['test'])); var_dump($_GET['test']); ?>
```

I have also tried

```
<?php var_dump(count($_POST['test'])); var_dump($_POST['test']); ?>
```

But the output is

```
int(0) NULL
```

Why can I see the variable in the URL but the variable contains NULL when using GET? All research seems to suggest this should be fine, or is it the way WordPress handles the URL?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance

Comment: The URL should be as  websiteurl.co.uk/?page_id=93&test=162

Comment: @Abhik ahh thanks for this it worked! - How can I mark this as the answer?

Comment: Added the answer u can mark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL needs to be as

```
websiteurl.co.uk/?page_id=93&test=162
```

Comment: Thanks Abhik much appreciated I will tick when timeout runs out!!